# How are methods invoked and returned by Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

There are various Mac developer libraries which invoke certain implemented methods when a certain event occurs. For instance, there is an `ImageCapture` framework which has many methods pertaining to a protocol which a delegate implements like `didAddDevice`, `didWindowLoad`, etc.

My question is when the method is invoked, where does the control reach after that methods finishes execution. I ask this because the project which I am working on involves use of such frameworks where - after the invoked method finishes execution, the program such hangs there i.e. I am not certain where the control has reached. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Add breakpoint and jump forward one line at the time and look what happens.

Comment: I have tried using breakpoint. The problem is that I don't where would the control go after the method so when I move forward after the end of function the application just stands there with the control reaching somewhere unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are invoked and return in Objective-C in a relatively ordinary way: When a method is to be called, a *message* is sent to the instance that should execute the method, consisting of the method name (which we call a *selector*), and pointers to the arguments and the caller (whom we call *sender*).

The important practical differences to how many other languages do this are:

Sending a message to nil does not result in a null pointer exception. It just gets quietly discarded, nothing happens, and you don't even get notified.

When an instance does not implement a selector, there are mechanisms in place that allow forwarding the message to other objects. This is rarely done, though.

You can ask an instance whether it implements a certain selector, and if it doesn't, choose not to send it a message (because that would crash).

So what happens in your concrete case?

The methods you are describing above get called on the delegate of the sender. They are likely optional, which means that if they are not implemented on the delegate (even though the delegate adheres to the protocol), the sender will see that they're not implanted and won't actually try to call them.

The other possibility is that you haven't set the delegate.

Comment: The method IS getting invoked. What I am trying to figure out is that where would the control return when the method execution finishes.

Comment: To the sender. And then, in your example, back to you.